# Object is not passed from view to controller when ViewModel is used

Tags: asp.net

*

Hey Guys need your help with data not being passed to controller. I encountered with emplty data passed from view to controller. So, whenever I use the viewmodel in the parameter of action method the posted object is properly passed but when I use customer model which inside the viewmodel then the data that I try to submit to database is not passed. Here is the view code:

*

```
@model WebApplication2.Models.CustomerViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "CreateForm";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>CreateForm</h2>

@using(Html.BeginForm("Create", "Customer"))
{
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m=>m.Customers.Name)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.Customers.Name, new { @class="form-control"})
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Customers.Birthdate)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Customers.Birthdate, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Customers.MembershipTypeId)
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Customers.MembershipTypeId, new SelectList(Model.MembershipTypes, "Id", "Name"),"Select", new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
    <button type"submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
}

Controller code

  [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(Customer customer)//data is not passed when I use Customer but is passed when CustomerViewModel is used
        {
            context.Customer.Add(customer);
            context.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Customer");
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look at the first line of your view, its:-

```
@model WebApplication2.Models.CustomerViewModel
```

so your view is a strongly typed view and its model is defined as CustomerViewModel. Accept a CustomerViewModel in your action method then make a new Customer object and populate its properties with CustomerViewModel's properties like:-

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(CustomerViewModel customerViewModel) 
{
    Customer customer = new Customer
    {
        //make customers properties = customerviewmodels properties
        customerName = customerViewModel.customerName        //etc
    };
    context.Customer.Add(customer);
    context.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Customer");
}
```

Comment: Hi Fakhar thank you for your attention and reply:) Yes you are right I have to put Customer instead of CustomerViewModel but CustomerViewModel holds two models as Customer and IEnumarable of MembershipType the code:  public class CustomerViewModel
    {
        public IEnumerable<MembershipType> MembershipTypes { get; set; }
        public Customer Customers { get; set; }
    }.So I need these models in the view IEnumerable is needed for dropdownlist and Customer for the other properties thus Customer in the view is not possible

Comment: then simply change your action method and accept CustomerViewModel instead of Customer, once you have the CustomerViewModel object in your action method then create a new Customer object and populate its properties with properties of CustomerViewModel. I have edited my answer, take a look

Comment: Wow, Fakhar I do not how to thank you your solution works perfectly many thanks to you "May Allah bless you"

Comment: @MirUsmanov no problem bro, please accept the answer if it helped :)